# Where does AuthorizationHandlerContext.User get created in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4

I have an `AuthorizationHandler` that evaluates some authorization requirements for [policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1#authorization-handlers).  Some part of ASP.NET Core calls `HandleRequirementAsync` with an instance of `AuthorizationHandlerContext`.

**Where does `AuthorizationHandlerContext.User` get populated?**

For context, I look up some properties in `AuthorizationContext.User` that correspond to OAuth2 claims in a JWT access token that is included in the HTTP request.  This is working fine when the JWT token was issued by IdentityServer4, but now I am adding support for access tokens to come from a secondary Identity Provider.

When the token is from this other provider, `AuthorizationContext.User` is a null object containing all-blank fields (i.e. it has none of the claims that are in the access token).  This secondary identity provider (and its public key) are included in the JWT Bearer authentication scheme in `TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers` and `TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys`, respectively.

This leads to the following log messages:

```
AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was successfully authenticated.
Authorization failed for user: <sub from the access token used in the request>
```

Comment: This is a bit of a moot question for me now, as I later realized I was adding two distinct authorities to a single AuthenticationScheme.  Once I switched over to using the more idiomatic workflow of configuring distinct AuthenticationSchemes, the context's user and claims seem to be populating just fine.

I did find through the debugger where the `HttpContext` gets created, although I don't mind if anyone has insight to share on how (or why not to try) to customize the way that ASP.NET Core creates the context and the user, from whatever JWT token/cookie that's available.

Comment: The process of defining multiple authentication schemes is defined here, in case it helps anyone else: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-multiple-authentication-schemes